# Qt invokeMethod and calling a static method?

Tags: c++, qt, invoke

Is it possible to call a static method?

I am using:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this
                         ,strThread.toLatin1()
                         ,Qt::DirectionConnection
                         ,Q_ARG(clsThread*, this));
```

This works, however I want to call a static method and that doesn't work, is it possible to invoke a static method?

I've tried assigning to strThread: "`clsScriptHelper::threadFun"`, but this doesn't work.

I couldn't get the static method to work, so I've implemented an alternative solution.  In my derived thread class I added a member which has the type:

```
QObject* mpobjClass;
```

I then added a method to set this:

void setClassPtr(QObject* pobjClass) { mpobjClass = pobjClass; }

My invoke now looks like this:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(mpobjClass
                         ,strThread.toLatin1()
                         ,Qt::DirectConnection
                         ,Q_ARG(clsThread*, this));
```

This works for me.

Comment: Solutions do not belong in questions: once you present a solution, it isn't a question anymore ("This works for me." is not a question). Please revert the edit and post your solution as an answer - it's perfectly fine to answer your own questions!

Comment: What is the scenario for calling a static method via `invokeMethod`? In any case, I don't understand the question anymore: The very first code snippet in your question has `invokeMethod(this, ...`. I presume that this is actual code that compiles (when you say "it doesn't work": what *exactly* do you mean?). Then your solution has `invokeMethod(mpobjClass, ...`) - what is the difference? Obviously, `invokeMethod` needs a pointer to the class, and since `this` is presumably the pointer you want, what even is the problem. Are you trying to call `invokeMethod` from a free function/static method??

Comment: @Kuba,  using the static call method where you prefix the method with the class name instead of an instance doesn't work when calling invokeMethod, that's what I mean.

Comment: Can you write a self-contained example of what you wish to accomplish, and add it to the question? Just a single `main.cpp` that begins with `#include <QtCore>`, ends with `#include "main.moc"`, and demonstrates why you want to do this. I smell an XY problem: you're asking for a solution to a problem that most likely should be solved in some other way. Show *why* you want to do what you ask for. This is predicated by involvement of threads: very often, explicit threads are not the answer, and result in all sorts of questions that don't need to be asked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can, but the method must be annotates as ***invocable*** i.e `Q_INVOKABLE` see [what qt documented about it...](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qobject.html#Q_INVOKABLE)

```
Foo obj;
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(&obj, "amSomething", Qt::DirectConnection);
```

and Foo should look like:

```
class Foo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Foo(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    Q_INVOKABLE static  void amSomething(){ qDebug() << "am in static";}
signals:

public slots:
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, where you have &obj, it won't have an instance as its a static call....

Comment: I've implemented an alternative solution which means I don't have to use a static method after all.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that? `invokeMethod` is for when the object has a dynamic type and you got an instance and want to call a method on that instance in spite of not knowing anything about the type.

What you seem to want to do is to dispatch static methods based on a string name. That's not hard and doesn't require `invokeMethod`:

```
class Class {
public:
  static void method1();
  static void method2();
  static void dispatchByName(const char *name) {
    if (QByteArrayLiteral("method1") == name) method1();
    else if (QByteArrayLiteral("method2") == name) method2();
  }
};
```

Comment: This isn't the problem, the problem is how to translate a string to a function call without having to do a switch or bunch of ifs.

Comment: The switch and ifs are there anyway, whether explicit or via a table. I guess you want to use moc to generate those tables and code for you?

Comment: No, I want the class to be portable and reusable with any literal method.